# SOAP WSDL PHP client connecting to .Net Server

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I need to integrate a web service, and its being like to days, and the closest I get is the following, maybe some of you have more experience than me in this kind of web service.

The XML request I need to generate is the following

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"         xmlns:v2="http://v2.services.cangooroo.net/" xmlns:can="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<v2:getCityData>
<v2:credentialClient>
<can:UserName>?</can:UserName>
<can:Password>?</can:Password>
</v2:credentialClient>
<v2:countryId>US</v2:countryId>
</v2:getCities>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My PHP code

```
 $client = new SoapClient("http://v2.cangooroo.net/ws/2013/common_a.asmx?WSDL", array(
       "trace" => 1,
       "compression" => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,
   ));
    $login = array();
    $login[] = new SoapVar('*', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'UserName', 'Cangooroo.Webservice.V2' );
    $login[] = new SoapVar('*', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'Password', 'Cangooroo.Webservice.V2' );
    $rest = array();
    $rest[] = new SoapVar($login, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'credentialClient' );
    $rest[] = new SoapVar('US', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'countryId');

    $options = array('location' => 'http://v2.cangooroo.net/ws/2013/common_a.asmx');

    try {
        $resp = $client->__soapCall('getCityData', $rest, $options);

        print_r($resp);
        echo "Request:<pre>" . htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()) . "</pre>";
    }catch (SoapFault $e){
        echo "REQUEST:<pre>" . htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()) . "</pre>";
        /*print_r($e);*/
```

The actual xml the PHP code above generates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns1="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2" xmlns:ns2="http://ws_2013.services.cangooroo.net/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns2:getCityData>
<ns1:UserName>*</ns1:UserName>
<ns1:Password>*</ns1:Password>
</ns2:getCityData><countryId>US</countryId></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Iam not really sure if this is the best way to do it, but I tryed others, with __soapCall, 
__doRequest, this last one I got the soapClient php core class extended (as a try) to connect, and nothing seems to work. Pls, I could use a little help here. Tks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the wsdl file in http://v2.cangooroo.net/ws/2013/common_a.asmx?WSDL you can see the definition of the `getCityData`

```
<s:element name="getCityData">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="credential" type="s1:ClientCredential"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="countryId" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

the operation `getCityData` has a `credential` parameter, not a `credentialClient` that is what you have in the code that you posted. I've tried with this code:

```
$wsdlAddress = "http://v2.cangooroo.net/ws/2013/common_a.asmx?WSDL";

$options = array(
    "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2,
    "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    "exceptions" => false
);

$webServiceClient = new SoapClient($wsdlAddress, $options);

$requestData = array(
    "countryId" => "US",
    "credential" => array(
        "UserName" => "username",
        "Password" => "Password",
    ),
);

$response = $webServiceClient->__soapCall("getCityData", array("getCityData" => $requestData));

echo "<h2>getCityData Operation Test:</h2>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
```

in the response i can see `Err: Login_Fail - Invalid user or password.`, i think i'm getting a valid response. Try with my code and adapt it to your needs.

Happy coding

Comment: Yes! It Works that way, and its a lot better! Thank you very much! I cant vote up, but I would. Thanks again!